# What is the best way to restart a node app automatically on 1) server restart AND 2) changes made to the files?

Tags: node.js, server, terminal

Apparently:

*nodemon* helps with changes to the files (e.g. you make changes to index.js)

*pm2* and *forever* keep the app running if you close the terminal, and can restart the app if it crashes.

But: What is the best combination or tool (and how to use it) to

1. Start the node app automatically on system boot/reboot
2. Restart the app automatically when changes are done to the files?

Comment: PM2 can do both, `watch` option is for watching the file changes.

Comment: Thank you, I checked and that's true.
"pm2 start main.js --watch" does the trick